# Regex: match until the second to last occurences of pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have this `text_string` list of strings. i want to extract all the `text_i_want` as one string.

```
text_string = ['text_i_dont_want aaaaaa aaaaaaa', 'text_i_want', 'text_i_want\ntext_i_want.', 'text_i_want.', 'text_i_dont_want\text_i_dont_want', 'number_i_dont_want']
```

I want to match everything already compiled below [everything after "`aaaaaa aaaaaaa ', '`"], until the second to last occurence of the following highlighted pattern: **', '**

```
ans = re.compile(r'aaaaaa\s+aaaaaaa\',\s+\'(.*)', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
ans_text = ans.search(str(text_string)).group(1)
```

returns

```
'text_i_want', 'text_i_want\ntext_i_want.', 'text_i_want.', 'text_i_dont_want\text_i_dont_want', 'number_i_dont_want'
```

So far, my regex is successfully matching the start of the string but is not stopping where i want it to (second to last pattern). I have no idea how to translate

```
until the second to last occurence of ', '
```

into regex language. Any help appreciated

Also, i want to do this with `re` because i have hundreds of those lists, which are all equal, **EXCEPT** for the number of times `'text_i_want.'` is occuring.

Example list, where the solution code should also work:

```
text_list2 = ['text_i_dont_want aaaaaa aaaaaaa', 'text_i_want', 'text_i_want.', 'text_i_dont_want\text_i_dont_want', 'number_i_dont_want']
```

UPDATED QUESTION:

some lists have a different ending than i said. The good news is that they have a specific character in them, that makes them unique.

```
text_list3 = ['text_i_dont_want aaaaaa aaaaaaa', 'text_i_want', 'text_i_want.', 'ttttttt tttttt', 'text_i_dont_want', 'text_i_dont_want', 'text_i_dont_want']

    rx = re.compile(r'aaa\s+aaa$')
    ans = [i for (i, x) in enumerate(text_string) if rx.search(x)]
    pattern = 'ttttttt tttttt'
    if ans:
        ans_text = text_list3[ans[0]+1:-2]
        if pattern in text_list3:
            ans_text = text_list3[ans[0]+1:-3]
```

Comment: `text_string` is not a string, it is a list. It makes sense to handle it as a list then.

Comment: So you want the strings which contain `text_i_want` to be printed?

Comment: PCM i want to store it in `ans_text` as it will be appended later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an item in the `text_string` (which is not a string but a list) that ends with the `aaaaaa aaaaaaa` string and then get all the items from the next one till the one you need with slicing:

```py
text_string = ['text_i_dont_want aaaaaa aaaaaaa', 'text_i_want', 'text_i_want\ntext_i_want.', 'text_i_want.', 'text_i_dont_want\text_i_dont_want', 'number_i_dont_want']
start = [i for (i, x) in enumerate( text_string ) if x.endswith('aaaaaa aaaaaaa')][0]
print( text_string[start+1:-2] )
# => ['text_i_want', 'text_i_want\ntext_i_want.', 'text_i_want.']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HSdYI1%5C)

If you prefer to check the `aaa`s with `re`, you can use

```py
import re
text_string = ['text_i_dont_want aaaaaa aaaaaaa', 'text_i_want', 'text_i_want\ntext_i_want.', 'text_i_want.', 'text_i_dont_want\text_i_dont_want', 'number_i_dont_want']
rx = re.compile(r'aaaaaa\s+aaaaaaa$')
start = [i for (i, x) in enumerate( text_string ) if rx.search(x)]
if start:
    print( text_string[start[0]+1:-2] )
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/xqPhJB).

Comment: thanks for you answer. I tried your `re` solution, which worked on this one list but not an all my other lists, which are the same as the list in the question except that the number of `, 'text_i_want.'` varies within them. That is why i wanted to use regex and not slicing. I think you misunderstood me because i was not precice enough. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: @id345678 It is not clear what you mean by "second to last" now. What is the stop condition?

Comment: EVERY list ends the same way: `...'text_i_want', 'text_i_dont_want', 'number_i_dont_want']` So the sop-condition is not the last time `', '` occurs, but the second to last time (between `'text_i_want` and `', '` `text_i_dont_want'`

Comment: @id345678 So, my solution [works for all three lists](https://ideone.com/Wbj8Sx).

Comment: Ahhh now i see some lists where the actual last two `'text_i_dont_want'` have two more `'text_i_dont_want'`. So in effect i would need to do -4 for those. Thanks Wiktor, you helped me a lot. Am i allowed to edit my question to include the unexpected but different condition?

Comment: @id345678 If you can guess what you need from the already given solution, I do not think that is necessary. Do that if your problem is still not solved.

Comment: @id345678 Try https://ideone.com/eqLFh1. Test for the end pattern, if it is there, take the last one and return all items between start and end. Else, get all from start till -2.

Comment: I added my solution to the question, which has the same output as your function on ideone. Namely, after the search, sometimes the 'ttt ttt' is the last item, which is not ideal but its good enough. I will use my solution as i have no idea how to incorporate your function into my otherwise primitive loops :D